# How to solve $f(x+f(x)+2f(y))=f(2x)+f(2y)$?

Tags: functional-equations

Another functional equation:

Find all surjective functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$ it satisfies:
$$
f(x+f(x)+2f(y))=f(2x)+f(2y)
$$
I couldn't make any progress because I didn't know how to use the surjectivity. How to solve it?

Answer (score 9):

Let $P(x,y)$ be the assertion $f(x+f(x)+2f(y))=f(2x)+f(2y)$ and let $a\in\mathbb R$ be such that $f(a)=0$.
$$
P(a,a):\space f(2a)=0\\
P(a,y):\space f(2f(y)+a)=f(2y)\implies\\
P(x,y):\space f(x+f(x)+2f(y))=f(2x)+f(2f(y)+a)
$$
Since $f$ is surjective, we may substitute $f(y)$ by $y$ and the assertion still holds for all $y\in\mathbb R$:
$$
P(x,y):\space f(x+f(x)+2y)=f(2x)+f(2y+a)\implies\\
P\left(2a,\frac{1}{2}a\right): f(3a)=0\\
P\left(x,-\frac{1}{2}f(x)\right):\space f(x)=f(2x)+f(-f(x)+a)=f(2f(x)+a)+f(-f(x)+a)\implies\\
x=f(2x+a)+f(-x+a)
$$
The last implication is again due to surjectivity. Furthermore, with $x=a$, we obtain $a=f(0)$. Now, we take a look at the original equation with $x=y=0$:
$$
f(3f(0))=2f(0)\implies a=f(0)=0
$$
Thus, $x=f(2x)+f(-x)$ and with $y=-\frac{1}{2}x$ in $f(x+f(x)+2y)=f(2x)+f(2y+a)$ we obtain $f(f(x))=f(2x)+f(-x)=x$. Thus, $f$ is injective. Now, with $y=0$, we have $f(x+f(x))=f(2x)\implies f(x)=x$ and we're done.